# Which http python proxy?

Tags: python, http, proxy

I want a very simple proxy written in python that will receive some http requests ,
it will discard the parameters and then based on the correctness of the parameters it proxy or not the request. Mostly for authentication.So i will write my little own code.What are you proposing? Does it sounds very trivial?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com).  It is a good fit for this kind of server.

[Here is an example of how to use it as a proxy](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/examples/)  Scroll to Virtual hosts and proxies

Answer (score 0):

I found also this one which works fine http://www.oki-osk.jp/esc/python/proxy/

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to use a proxy to access certain websites that are foreign and you can access locally you would want to add this to your script

```
Proxy1 = '188.166.174.77:80'

proxies = {
             'http': 'http://' + Proxy1 + '',
                 'https': 'https://' + Proxy1 + ''

}

r1 = requests.get('url', proxies=proxies)
```